# How to make phpmyadmin work with NGINX

Tags: nginx, centos

I have tried many things but I cant seem to make it work.
I am running CentOS6 64-bit. Latest NGINX version installed.
I cannot seem to go to http://domain.com/phpmyadmin aftet switching from Apache.
Please help, thanks.

Here is my Default.conf:

```
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  login.php index.php;

    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

EDIT:
***FIXED***

Moved the PHPMYADMIN folder from /usr/share to my web directory.

Comment: when the phpmyadmin package is updated you won't get the updates, because that folder isn't managed by the update manager.

Answer (score 0):

And now you broke the package. For prosperity:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share;
}
```